# Drag and Drop swap complete object not just innertext

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have the following code which swaps out one divs innerHTML for the others on a DND based situation.

```
dragSrcEl = //This is the var that is assigned to the object that is being dragged, appears outside of this code below.

dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
```

What would I have to do, if i wanted it to change everything, namely the whole container, all its rels, propertys, classnames, id's, data attributes e.t.c

I cannot re-order it within the dom, due to the dynamic way that each of these will be dragged and dropped about...

Many thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will do the moving:

```
$(dargSrcEl).replaceWith(this);
```

Comment: .empty() is for items within the container. Doing that merly adds the one div inside the other.

Comment: And I have though that is what you wanted.

Comment: I have edited my answer with another guess of what you might be looking for. If it is not it, then I think should try being more clear about what you want to do within your question.